# matplotlib: multiple legends in each single subplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, subplot

I know how to split the legend of a plot into two separate legends:

```py
x = np.linspace(0,1)
y1 = x
y2 = 2*x

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
fig.set_size_inches((8,8))

points = []
pnts = ax.scatter(x, y1, c='b')
points.append(pnts)
pnts = ax.scatter(x, y2, marker='v', c='r')
points.append(pnts)

leg1 = plt.legend([points[0]], ['blue'],\
                  loc=2, ncol=1, fancybox=False, shadow=False, framealpha=0.0, fontsize = 25)

leg2 = plt.legend([points[1]], ['red'],\
                  loc=4, ncol=1, fancybox=False, shadow=False, framealpha=0.0, fontsize = 25)

ax.add_artist(leg1)
ax.add_artist(leg2)
```

This produces the nice figure you expect:

[image: Figure]

What I need to do is to extend this method to multiple subplots in a single figure. I thought the natural extension would have been

```py
x = np.linspace(0,1)
y1 = x
y2 = 2*x

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 2, sharex = False, sharey = False)
fig.set_size_inches((16,8))


#################


points = []
pnts = ax[0].scatter(x, y1, c='b')
points.append(pnts)
pnts = ax[0].scatter(x, y2, marker='v', c='r')
points.append(pnts)

leg1 = plt.legend([points[0]], ['blue'],\
                  loc=2, ncol=1, fancybox=False, shadow=False, framealpha=0.0, fontsize = 25)

leg2 = plt.legend([points[1]], ['red'],\
                  loc=4, ncol=1, fancybox=False, shadow=False, framealpha=0.0, fontsize = 25)

ax[0].add_artist(leg1)
ax[0].add_artist(leg2)


#################


points = []
pnts = ax[1].scatter(x, y1, c='g')
points.append(pnts)
pnts = ax[1].scatter(x, y2, marker='orange', c='r')
points.append(pnts)

leg1 = plt.legend([points[0]], ['green'],\
                  loc=2, ncol=1, fancybox=False, shadow=False, framealpha=0.0, fontsize = 25)

leg2 = plt.legend([points[1]], ['orange'],\
                  loc=4, ncol=1, fancybox=False, shadow=False, framealpha=0.0, fontsize = 25)

ax[1].add_artist(leg1)
ax[1].add_artist(leg2)
```

Unfortunately, what I get is

> ax[0].add_artist(leg1)
>   ValueError: Can not reset the axes.  You are probably trying to re-use an artist in more than one Axes which is not supported

It looks like that it can't be used with multiple subplots... Even if something that surprises me is that the error is given the first time I try to call `add_artist`.

Note, finally, that I may probably come up with some brute force solution such as making a separate ax for each legend or something like this. I would rather prefer a more automatized solution able to deal with potentially many subplots and legends in a relatively simple manner.

Comment: Instead of `plt.legend` use `ax[0].legend`and `ax[1].legend`. Also, for me, `marker='orange'` gives `Unrecognized marker style 'orange'`.

Comment: Yes in the last example, orange should have been the color. However, `ax.legen` made the trick. Thanks.